# VSCode status bar - what does this symbol mean

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: mystery]

What is the `{..}:456` trying to tell me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right-click on status bar items to get a "Manage Extension" context menu. This will let you know which extension contributed it.

The upcoming VSCode 1.36 release also allows hiding specific status bar items via this context menu.